# ASP.Net Core handle product prices

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a fairly simple question, but I'm not quite sure how to explain what it is I'm trying to do so I'll start with some code:

```
public IActionResult Charge(string stripeEmail, string stripeToken)
{
    ViewData["Price"] = Price;
    ViewData["Description"] = Description;
    if (StripeHelpers.ChargeCustomer(stripeEmail, stripeToken, Price, Description))
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    return RedirectToAction("Failure");
}

public IActionResult Success()
{
    ViewData["Price"] = Price;
    ViewData["Description"] = Description;

    return View();
}

public IActionResult Failure()
{
    ViewData["Price"] = Price;
    ViewData["Description"] = Description;

    return View();
}
```

This is my controller for a product page and I'd like to find an alternative to setting the ViewData for every action since it's basically a constant in the controller setting the price and transaction description.

Is there a better, more re-usable solution? Preferably a one-liner I can add to my controller to automatically inject information into all of its views.

Sure, I can do without this specific data in this instance but I'm sure I'll come a cross a similar problem in the future and I'd love to learn the ins and outs of ASP.Net Core anyway.

Comment: Do you need Price and Description added to all your view models? Is your code just like the one you posted? If it is, you should just create a view model (a class) to store the info the views need, and simply pass it in each method. Are you familiar with MVC? Where are these two values? Are they controller properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you need to set `ViewData` everytime is because you're redirecting. Redirecting makes `ViewData` values to null. This is mostly because it's just a mechanism for the view and the controller to communicate.

You can use  `TempData` to work with it though. `TempData` should be able to pass on data from one action to another action. Note: TempData only exists up to one pass.

Your example:

```
public IActionResult Charge(string stripeEmail, string stripeToken)
{
    TempData["Price"] = Price;
    TempData["Description"] = Description;
    if (StripeHelpers.ChargeCustomer(stripeEmail, stripeToken, Price, Description))
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    return RedirectToAction("Failure");
}

public IActionResult Success()
{
    return View();
}

public IActionResult Failure()
{
    return View();
}
```

And you can access the data on your views using `TempData`, you just need to box it.

```
var price = (int)TempData['Price'];
```

This, theoretically, will work but it's bad practice. I suggest passing the data using a view model. Basically, you create another class with `Product` and `Description` on it, assign it a value, and pass it on whenever you redirect. You then pass it as a model of the view, and use that model on  that view. That way, you follow MVC's patterns.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the Reusable solution for you:**
Make a private method which will return Price and Description ViewData.Then Call it in your action methods.

```
   private void ReturnPriceAndDescription()
    {
       ViewData["Price"] = Price;
       ViewData["Description"] = Description;
    }

    public IActionResult Charge(string stripeEmail, string stripeToken)
    {
        ReturnPriceAndDescription();
        if (StripeHelpers.ChargeCustomer(stripeEmail, stripeToken, Price, Description))
            return RedirectToAction("Success");
        return RedirectToAction("Failure");
    }

    public IActionResult Success()
    {
        ReturnPriceAndDescription();
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Failure()
    {
        ReturnPriceAndDescription();
        return View();
    }
```